# ¿Como elimino el recuadro azul, que se hace al seleccionar el icono de menu en movil y permanece indefinidamente, desde iphone?

Tags: css, ios

Hola que tal? ¿Como elimino el recuadro azul que se hace al seleccionar el icono de menu en movil y permanece indefinidamente?, Solo se ve desde los iphone (ios) mas nuevos, no se ve desde android ni los iphone con ios mas viejos, Gracias!

**[image: .]**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Como no agregaste ningún código (lo cual es necesario), voy a suponer que en tu archivo *CSS* falte dos propiedades.

1. **-webkit-tap-highlight-color**. *Es una propiedad CSS no estándar que fija el color que sirve para destacar un enlace cuando se golpea  sobre él*. Pero como esto no es estándar y puede que no te funcione (como dicen la  [Documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-tap-highlight-color)), puede resultar la siguiente:
2. **outline**. *La propiedad CSS `outline-style` es usada para establecer el estilo del contorno de un elemento* ([documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/outline-style)).

Para usar estas dos propiedades, hay varias formas; siempre en CSS:

Declarar de forma global al inicio de todos:

```
* {
 outline: none;
 -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}
```

Ó se puede declarar en el HTML, o en el body:

```
body {
 outline: none;
 -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}
```

Ó también se puede declarar al DOM, que en este caso es tu icono "X".
Suponiendo que este icono tenga una clase `close`, entonces:

```
.close {
 outline: none;
 -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}
```

Si no te funciona con estas propiedades que supongo que es solo eso, entonces sería necesario especificar más tú problema agregando código.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, en efecto era eso, intente con la primera y logre quitarlo!

Comment: @EstefaníaMolina Si esta respuesta soluciona tu pregunta deberias aceptarla para que la pregunta no quede pendiente pasa siempre (a pesar de estar cerrada aun puedes aceptar la respuesta). Puedes consultar como se aceptan las respuestas visitando este [enlace](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/428/263200).